# Using booleans on objects.filter() in Django

Tags: django, django-models

How would I use booleans on an objects filter. For example --

`Emails.objects.filter(id=1 or id=2)`

`Emails.objects.filter(name='tom' and domain = 'gmail.com')`

How would these translate into useable syntax? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Emails.objects.filter(id__in=[1, 2])

Emails.objects.filter(name='tom', domain='gmail.com')
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do OR is to use [Q](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects). You can AND and OR them just like booleans

```
# Filter emails whose id is 1 or 2
Emails.objects.filter(Q(id=1) | Q(id=2))
```

Of course the intended use of Q is so that you can construct queries like

```
# Filter emails whose id is 1 or name is 'tom'
Emails.objects.filter(Q(id=1) | Q(name='tom'))
```

To do AND the obvious way is to specify one attribute after another like in Ignacio's answer :)